# VimeoAPIException - Uncaught exception with message 'Not allowed'

Tags: php, vimeo-api

When I try to set video privacy exceptions is thrown.

```
$vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.setPrivacy', array('privacy' => 'anybody', 'video_id' => $video_id));
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is part of the old, deprecated Advanced API. Please switch to the [new API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api).

To set the video privacy using the new API, and the new [PHP Library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php), you can use the following code

`$vimeo = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);
$vimeo->setToken($token);
$vimeo->request('/videos/' . $video_id, array(
    'privacy' => array('view' => 'anybody')
), 'PATCH');`